# multidimensional database without cubes

Tags: database, oracle, olap

Is it possible to create multidimensional database without cubes (OLAP), just use tables connected in star schema and use some optimisation power of modern bases (like Oracle 12)? And then just use BI tool directly on the tables in business mart.

Can you please explain more deeply is it possible or not?

Comment: Postgres user here, close enough...  CTE's and Window functions let me get away with a lot these days.  Far fewer intermediate tables than in years past.  I haven't looked into grouping sets or rollups yet but they seem very interesting as well.

Comment: Can you?  Sure.  Probably.  Depending on what you're doing.  Might you get faster performance using OLAP cubes rather than purely relational tables?  Sure.  Probably.  Depending on what you're doing.

Comment: Of course it is possible - you are not required to do analytics if you don't need to. But do you? In any case, you can definitely create tables connected in a star schema (with all the proper primary and foreign keys, check constraints, ....), use CTE's, joins of all kinds, hierarchical queries, recursive queries, analytical and aggregate functions, model clause, XQuery, materialized views, ....   Why would you think you must use cube extensions (which are only a very small part of what an Oracle db does)?